# Multiple input files in Scalding

Tags: scalding

I want to process a *large* number of textfiles stored in s3. Unfortunately, I cannot simply use a list together with the MultipleTextLineFiles source because the method code becomes too large and a java.lang.RuntimeException is thrown.

My last attempt was to ship the jar file with a textfile containing the list of files, which is then read using "scala.io.Source.fromURL(getClass.getResource(filename)).getLines().toSeq"
but this fails with a NoSuchElementException being thrown.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: Why not just pass the directory containing all the files?

Answer (score 1):

try passing all the file names as args to a Class, and then handle them accordingly (loop over the args list, or handle them individually):

```
import com.twitter.scalding.{ Args, Job }

class someScalaClass(args: Args) extends Job(args) {
   args.restrictTo(Set("arg1", "arg2") 
   val someFile = args.getOrElse("arg1").read
}
```

im not sure what else to say without more context info, if you could please edit and provide moar details

Answer (score 0):

If all your files are in the same folder and you need to process all of them, just pass the folder path as input arg to TextLine. It will read all of files inside it (for s3, you need to execute your job on EMR though).

Comment: I am trying to do this but I keep getting a java.io.FileNotFoundException saying that my input param "is a directory". Can you elaborate? I'm running the WordCountJob.scala example that came with the Scalding repo on GitHub and passed it an input folder with three input text files.

Comment: @thecomputerwhisperer did you have '/' at the end of path name?

Comment: Yep, still the same @piggybox. Does it have anything to do with the fact that I'm trying to run in local mode?

Comment: @thecomputerwhisperer Are you using scald.rb to start the scalding job? It's not recommended any more. You should follow the scalding tutorial in cascading project using hadoop to start the job, which is the same way you will use scalding in production.

Comment: ok, cool. Do you have any tutorial suggestions that helped you get started?

Comment: I'd say follow https://github.com/Cascading/scalding-tutorial . This is the same scalding tutorial but has been ported to hadoop2 and use sbt instead of scald.rb to start. It's running under the pseudo-local mode of hadoop. After this you can read through the API wiki to get familiar with various scalding functions